# Pass variable to get JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have JSON data as the response of a query. Then end-user makes two selections from UI and program retrieves the data from the JSON. User's selections are stored in `cityNumber` and `selectParam` variables. I want to pass these two variable as the keys. I could pass the `cityNumber` in `[]` but `selectParam` gives error since there is not any key named as `selectParam`. How can I retrieve the data by passing the `selectParam` dynamically?

`var results = locations[cityNumber].data.selectParam.timeValuePairs;`

Comment: `locations[cityNumber].data[selectParam].timeValuePairs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Use like this***

> var results = locations[cityNumber]["data"][selectParam][
>   "timeValuePairs"];

Comment: @yalcinm1  upvote and accept answer if its useful. Thank YOu